# Send and retrieve Map using URLConnection

Tags: java

I want to send HashMap from Swing Application to Web Application.HashMap type is . It contains One String, ArrayList and Byte Array. I want to retrieve this Map in web Application.

Swing Side Code:

```
private static void sendMap()
    {
        System.out.println("Sending MAP");
        byte[] bytes=getByteArray();
        ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("ABC");
        list.add("XYZ");
        list.add("ABXY");
        Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("Type", "Document");
        params.put("bytes", bytes);
        params.put("PartyNameList", list);

        try {
            URL url=  new URL(iinkiturl+"/getMap?id=1234567");
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            uc.setDoOutput(true);
            uc.setDoInput(true);
            uc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

            DataOutputStream dstream = new DataOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());

            // The POST line
            System.out.println(toByteArray(params));
            dstream.write(params.toString().getBytes());
            dstream.close();

             InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
            int x;
            while ((x = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.write(x);
            }
            in.close();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line);
            }


        } catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Web Application Side:

```
        InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine())!=null) {
        buf.append(line);
        } 
        System.out.println("Buffer ======= "+buf.toString());
```

Output:

Buffer ======= {Type=Filing, PartyNameList=[ABC, XYZ, ABXY], bytes=[B@24c0f1ec}

How can I get Map object from this Buffer. Or is there any alternate solution to achieve this. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: See XML or JSON notation, and the APIs to produce and consume them in Java...

Comment: Use Arrays.toString to fix the byte array

Comment: Usually projects grow build on some framework. Almost all have concept to encode / decode arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved using JSON.

Swing Side Code:

```
private static void sendMap()
    {
        System.out.println("Sending MAP");
        ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("ABC");
        list.add("XYZ");
        list.add("ABXY");
        Map<String, Object> params=new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("Type", "Document");
        params.put("bytes", getByteArray());
        params.put("NameList", list);

        try {
            URL url=  new URL(iinkiturl+"/getMap?id=1234567");
            URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
            uc.setDoOutput(true);
            uc.setDoInput(true);
            uc.setAllowUserInteraction(false);

            DataOutputStream dstream = new DataOutputStream(uc.getOutputStream());

            dstream.write(new com.google.gson.Gson().toJson(params).getBytes());
            dstream.close();

             InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
            int x;
            while ((x = in.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.write(x);
            }
            in.close();

            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(line);
            }


        } catch(Exception exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Web Application Side:

```
InputStream in = request.getInputStream();
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine())!=null) {
  buf.append(line);
} 


Map<String,Object> map=convertJsonToMap(buf.toString());

private Map<String, Object> convertJsonToMap(String json) {

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {

            // convert JSON string to Map
            map = mapper.readValue(json,new TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>>() {});

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using just `toString()` method. It's not possible to do deserialization from it.
Use JSON or Java Serialization tools for moving Map to the transferable state (view). And the same tools at the client side to deserialize it.

Comment: Anything can deserialized (if the byte array was printed correctly) , it just requires a custom parser

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't think so. Only truly serialized object can be deserialized. `Anything` can not to be deserialized.

Comment: A consistently formatted string can be deserialized ;)

Comment: @cricket_007 `A consistently formatted string` is already truly serialized :)

Comment: I guess I mean just parsed, then

Comment: I mean, it's not possible to use default `Map.toString()` for transfering object. You need to use some popular solution like JSON, XML, Java serialization, Protobuf and etc. Or you have to make your own.
In this case you need to make serializator and deserializator.
@cricket_007

Comment: That I agree with.

Answer (score 0):

Using `toString()` in your case generates string representation of the HashMap and sends it over the network not the actual `HashMap` , which is why you see that representation on the Web Application side.

You should rather make use of `ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream` classes to send/receive your **HashMap** .

`ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream` are specifically concerned with sending Object across network.

However this requires that all objects that you want to send over the
network(This process is referred to as **Serialization**) must implement the Serializable interface, which is a marker interface.